# PyQt QTableWidget retrieve edited field

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am fairly new to PyQt and I am making a GUI in PyQt4 and Python 2.7 that (among other things) controls the settings of a handful of micro-controllers. To easily populate and display the list of settings, and which controller they are from I have put it into a QTableWidget with the columns being the controllers and the rows being the settings (all controllers are simply duplicates of each other, though not all settings will be the same value from controller to controller).

The problem I am having is that when the user edits the cell I try to get that new value with

```
value = self.Settings1Table.item(n, s).text()
```

but that only retrieves the value that I placed in the cell during population, not the value that was just entered via the keyboard. I have read about a method `currentText()` but from what I understand, that requires each cell to be its own widget, and I'm not sure how that is done.

The entire code is quite large, and I felt that it was unnecessary to post it in its entirety, but if more of the code is needed, I'll be happy to provide. Thank you for the help I hope is to come.

Edit: Here is the method that iterates through each item in the table, its supposed to get the current value, but right now only returns the value that I have set via item.setText(str) (needs to be the value that the user inputted via keyboard)

```
def ApplyAll1(self):
    if not self.CheckHealth():
        for s in xrange(NumOfSegs):
            n = 0
            for item in Settings1List:
                value = self.Settings1Table.item(n, s).text()
                print value
    else:
        self.MsgCntrField.setText("CONNECTION ERROR")
```

The self.CheckHealth() is just error checking

Comment: So, your question "How I get edited data for QTableWidget when user edit data, tack it to variable". right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LAST UPDATED 8 / 19 / 2014 0 : 29**

> I don't really care about the event, since I am going to loop through
>   the entire table, I do need the data changed by the keyboard instead
>   of 'QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.setText' so yes

OK, It's possibly to create event then keyboard only, but your have to implement `QtGui.QTableWidget.focusInEvent(self, eventQFocusEvent)` and `QtGui.QTableWidget.focusOutEvent(self, eventQFocusEvent)`. So, please see ny example code, hope is help;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.focusKeyboardOn = False
        # Setup row & column data
        listsVerticalHeaderItem = ['Device 1', 'Device 2', 'Device 3', 'Device 4', 'Device 5']
        self.setRowCount(len(listsVerticalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setVerticalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsVerticalHeaderItem[index]))
        listsVerticalHeaderItem = ['Device 1', 'Device 2', 'Device 3', 'Device 4']
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        listsHorizontalHeaderItem = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
        self.setColumnCount(len(listsHorizontalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsHorizontalHeaderItem[index]))

    def dataChanged (self, topLeftQModelIndex, bottomRightQModelIndex):
        row                  = topLeftQModelIndex.row()
        column               = topLeftQModelIndex.column()
        dataQTableWidgetItem = self.item(row, column)
        if (self.currentItem() == dataQTableWidgetItem) and (self.focusKeyboardOn == True):
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('currentKeyboardDataChanged'), row, column, dataQTableWidgetItem)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dataChanged'), row, column, dataQTableWidgetItem)
        QtGui.QTableWidget.dataChanged(self, topLeftQModelIndex, bottomRightQModelIndex)

    def focusInEvent (self, eventQFocusEvent):
        self.focusKeyboardOn = False
        QtGui.QTableWidget.focusInEvent(self, eventQFocusEvent)

    def focusOutEvent (self, eventQFocusEvent):
        self.focusKeyboardOn = True
        QtGui.QTableWidget.focusOutEvent(self, eventQFocusEvent)

class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget(self)
        self.myQLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Track edited data', self)
        myQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        myQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQLabel)
        myQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQCustomTableWidget)
        self.setLayout(myQVBoxLayout)
        self.connect(self.myQCustomTableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('currentKeyboardDataChanged'), self.setTrackData)
        self.myQCustomTableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Test'))
        self.myQCustomTableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Work'))

    def setTrackData (self, row, column, dataQTableWidgetItem):
        self.myQLabel.setText('Last updated\nRow : %d, Column : %d, Data : %s' % (row + 1, column + 1, str(dataQTableWidgetItem.text())))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomWidget = QCustomWidget()
    myQCustomWidget.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

**NOTE : It have 1 codition to have BUG: If your set by 'QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.setText' while edit via keyboard active. But if your strict it case,** I suggest create your own widget and set item delegate your own. (But, very hardcore ...)

---

I don't know what is data in your cell what is it. (It's another custom `QWidget` or it just normal data `QTableWidgetItem`)

Anyway, when the user edits the cell your try to get that new value with this method `QAbstractItemView.dataChanged (self, QModelIndex topLeft, QModelIndex bottomRight)`. This method return position of data has edited and your get data from index by use `QTableWidgetItem QTableWidget.item (self, int row, int column)`. (That what your say it question) But this work only edit has close (Not during edit).

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # Setup row & column data
        listsVerticalHeaderItem = ['Device 1', 'Device 2', 'Device 3', 'Device 4', 'Device 5']
        self.setRowCount(len(listsVerticalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setVerticalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsVerticalHeaderItem[index]))
        listsVerticalHeaderItem = ['Device 1', 'Device 2', 'Device 3', 'Device 4']
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        listsHorizontalHeaderItem = ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
        self.setColumnCount(len(listsHorizontalHeaderItem))
        for index in range(self.columnCount()):
            self.setHorizontalHeaderItem(index, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(listsHorizontalHeaderItem[index]))

    def dataChanged (self, topLeftQModelIndex, bottomRightQModelIndex):
        row                  = topLeftQModelIndex.row()
        column               = topLeftQModelIndex.column()
        dataQTableWidgetItem = self.item(row, column)
        print '###### Data Changed  ######'
        print 'row    :', row + 1
        print 'column :', column + 1
        print 'data   :', dataQTableWidgetItem.text()
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('dataChanged'), row, column, dataQTableWidgetItem)
        QtGui.QTableWidget.dataChanged(self, topLeftQModelIndex, bottomRightQModelIndex)

class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget(self)
        self.myQLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Track edited data', self)
        myQVBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        myQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQLabel)
        myQVBoxLayout.addWidget(self.myQCustomTableWidget)
        self.setLayout(myQVBoxLayout)
        self.connect(self.myQCustomTableWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('dataChanged'), self.setTrackData)

    def setTrackData (self, row, column, dataQTableWidgetItem):
        self.myQLabel.setText('Last updated\nRow : %d, Column : %d, Data : %s' % (row + 1, column + 1, str(dataQTableWidgetItem.text())))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomWidget = QCustomWidget()
    myQCustomWidget.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

---

**`QAbstractItemView.dataChanged (self, QModelIndex topLeft, QModelIndex bottomRight)` Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#dataChanged

---

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am having trouble figuring out how this code knows when the field has been edited. I don't see any signals for cellChanged or any way for the program to know that focus has been changed. Where does this change actually occur? My code iterates through all of the cells, so knowing which one has been changed isn't very important, just having the changed data be callable (i assume with item.text() ) I'm adding to OP my "apply" code that takes all the supposedly current values (but arent actually current, hence my problem)

Comment: Also, to answer your first question, the data I am referring to is QTableWidgetItem

Comment: Now, I very confused (sorry). My program (this answer code) show how to get index (row and column) and data when field has been edited (So, during edit isn't not to do anything). This code it known automatic if data has been changed and your can get data changed it or index them. You says, " I don't see any signals for cellChanged or any way for the program to know that focus has been changed." This not signal, It's just event then data has been edited.

Comment: Or, your want to track event then data cheaged form keyboard input only, not 'QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.setText', right ?

Comment: I don't really care about the event, since I am going to loop through the entire table, I do need the data changed by the keyboard instead of 'QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.setText' so yes

Comment: I should also mention that I have run your code, and it does do what I want it to, but I haven't been able to successfully integrate it into my program